# Tkinter entry widget .get doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am fairly new to python and am currently working on a school project, my aim is to create a search bar that can be used to search a data file, however I am struggling to get the search bar to work correctly. I am using the tkinter entry widget.
When I call .get(), the string in the entry widget is not printed. Here is my code...

```
from tkinter import *

def searchButton():
        text = searched.get()
        print (text)

def drawStatWindow():
    global searched
    statWindow = Tk()
    statWindow.title("View Statistics")
    statWindow.config(bg = "grey")
    statWindow.geometry('800x900')

    searched = StringVar()
    searchBox = Entry(statWindow, textvariable = searched)
    searchBox.place(x= 450, y=50, width = 200, height = 24)
    enterButton = tkinter.Button(statWindow, text ="Enter", command =searchButton)
    enterButton.config(height = 1, width = 4)
    enterButton.place(x=652, y=50)

drawStatWindow()
```

When I type a string into the entry widget and press the enter button, nothing happens.
Like I say I am not very experienced and this is my first project, but after reading about the tkinter entry widgets I can't understand why this won't work.
I am using python V3.4.0
Thanks.

Comment: The code in your question won't run. Please take the time to post _actual_ code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks a call to `mainloop()`. You could try adding it to the end of the `drawStatWindow()` function:

```
statWindow.mainloop()
```

You might want to restructure your code into a class. This allows you to avoid using global variables and generally provides better organisation for your application:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, statWindow):
        statWindow.title("View Statistics")
        statWindow.config(bg = "grey")
        statWindow.geometry('800x900')

        self.searched = StringVar()
        searchBox = Entry(statWindow, textvariable=self.searched)
        searchBox.place(x= 450, y=50, width = 200, height = 24)
        enterButton = Button(statWindow, text ="Enter", command=self.searchButton)
        enterButton.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        enterButton.place(x=652, y=50)

    def searchButton(self):
        text = self.searched.get()
        print(text)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been wanting to restructure my code like this, however I've never used classes before so this gives me a good starting point. I will look into this more and try and restructure my whole program like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `mainloop()` because `tkinter` needs it to run.

If you run code in IDLE which use `tkinter` then IDLE runs own `mainloop()` and code can work but normally you have to add `mainloop()` at the end.

And you have to remove `tkinter` in `tkinter.Button`.

```
from tkinter import *

def searchButton():
    text = searched.get()
    print(text)

def drawStatWindow():
    global searched

    statWindow = Tk()
    statWindow.title("View Statistics")
    statWindow.config(bg="grey")
    statWindow.geometry('800x900')

    searched = StringVar()

    searchBox = Entry(statWindow, textvariable=searched)
    searchBox.place(x= 450, y=50, width=200, height=24)

    # remove `tkinter` in `tkinter.Button`
    enterButton = Button(statWindow, text="Enter", command=searchButton)
    enterButton.config(height=1, width=4)
    enterButton.place(x=652, y=50)

    # add `mainloop()`
    statWindow.mainloop()

drawStatWindow()
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to use textvariable, you should use this:

```
searchBox = Entry(statWindow)
searchBox.focus_set()
searchBox.place(x= 450, y=50, width = 200, height = 24)
```

then you will be able to use searchBox.get(), that will be a string.

Comment: Thanks this works fine! Just out of interest what is the focus_set() doing?

Comment: It returns the string written in the entry, I don't know better than that.

Comment: No, `focus_set()` does _not_ "return the string written in the entry". Like the name implies, it merely sets the focus into the entry. It has no effect on the result of `searchBox.get()`.

Comment: Yes, it works. The wrong thing I said was it returns a string. You will recieve a string with get()